Locate image on screen but the image can be rotated
I want to locate an image on the screen that might be rotated using Python. To be specific, this is my search image:

However, it might appear on my screen like this:

The image above is rotated using artificial methods, but this is just an example. So how might I do it? I know that if there is no rotation, I can do it with pyautogui:
pyautogui.locateOnScreen("image.png")

One solution I have tried is to rotate the image many times and locate it on my screen with a confidence parameter. However, it is too time-consuming. Even if I use threads, then it is too memory-consuming.
Any help is welcome, for example, certain optimization methods, or other usable functions.

Try to narrow down search first (for example search for image parts with similar pixel color distributions), then do exactly what you did, but only on most promising parts
